# how can i use scapy to get special layers from pkt1 to another pkt2?

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

Now i have one pkt like this: ether-ip-udp-vxlan-ether-ipv6-tcp, and i want to get some layers of that like: ether_ip_udp, i don't want layers of ether_ipv6_tcp.

`pkt=Ether()/IP()/UDP()/VXLAN()/Ether()/IPv6()/TCP()`

i tried to use getlayer, but it will get next layer, it's not whar i want.
`pkt=Ether()/IP()/UDP()/VXLAN()/Ether()/IPv6()/TCP()`

`pkt.getlayer(Ether)`

it will get all next layers.

how can i do this in **scapy**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy and trim the packet:

```
pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP()/VXLAN()/Ether()/IPv6()/TCP()
pkt2 = pkt.copy()
pkt2[UDP].remove_payload()
```

Comment: @WuDangWangYe if this answers your question, please mark it as such

Comment: another question is that : i have one pktList as pkts, it include 10+ pkt， when i tried ```pkts[UDP]``` in scapy‘s interactive mode, it works well, but when i use it in my code, it raiser ```TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not Packet_metaclass```;my code is follows:```pkts = pkts[IP].filter(lambda  x:x[IP].dst in ipnet(dst_ip))```, ```ipnet``` is equal to ```IPy.IP```.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the first 3 layers, you need to convert the packet to layers and then construct a new packet with the layers you care about. There are likely other methods to do this same thing.

```py
# original_name_for_script.py
from scapy.all import *

pkt = Ether()/IP()/UDP()/VXLAN()/Ether()/IPv6()/TCP()
layers = pkt.layers()
# Equivalent of calling Ether()/IP()/UDP(), but for existing packet
new_pkt = layers[0]()/layers[1]()/layers[2]()
new_pkt.summary()
```

Running this script, we get

```sh
$ python original_name_for_script.py
'Ether / IP / UDP 127.0.0.1:domain > 127.0.0.1:domain'
```

Comment: i tried as u said, but it missed metadata in IP Header